# How to use data from one observation in two observations in a merge, with R?

Tags: r

I want to merge two tables, but I need to fill the data of one observation with x name, with the information from another observation with y name (similar).

```
oem <- c("BMW_", "BMW", "Honda", "Toyota", "Ford", "Audi")
> units <- c(215, 43, 324, 313, 350, 90)
> sales <- tibble(oem, units)
> sales
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  oem    units
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 BMW_     215
2 BMW       43
3 Honda    324
4 Toyota   313
5 Ford     350
6 Audi      90
> 
> oem2 <- c("BMW", "Honda", "Toyota", "Ford", "Audi")
> point_sales <- c(121, 231, 145, 132, 183)
> ps <- tibble(oem2,point_sales) 
> variables <- c("oem", "point_sales")
> names(ps) = variables
> ps
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  oem    point_sales
  <chr>        <dbl>
1 BMW            121
2 Honda          231
3 Toyota         145
4 Ford           132
5 Audi           183
> 
> 
> base <- merge(sales,ps, by = "oem", all = TRUE)
> base
     oem units point_sales
1   Audi    90         183
2    BMW    43         121
3   BMW_   215          NA
4   Ford   350         132
5  Honda   324         231
6 Toyota   313         145
```

I need to fill my "BMW_" row in base with the information from "BMW" of "ps" ("point_sales"), so, this implies that the data from "ps" of "BMW" will be repeated for "BMW" as well as for "BMW_", avoiding the NA in "point_sales" column.

I am newbie, so I think about copy and paste the data manually, but I want to know if there is another way more "elegant" or more according to R.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `stringdist_inner_join` from `fuzzyjoin` package.

```
fuzzyjoin::stringdist_inner_join(sales, ps, by = 'oem')

#  oem.x  units oem.y  point_sales
#  <chr>  <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
#1 BMW_     215 BMW            121
#2 BMW       43 BMW            121
#3 Honda    324 Honda          231
#4 Toyota   313 Toyota         145
#5 Ford     350 Ford           132
#6 Audi      90 Audi           183
```